# What do you call it when someone does or says something and then it becomes a saying?

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

For example, say in discussion with someone, you gave something a "name" for something that they did - for this example let's just say you referenced what they did as they "white-collared it" and it caught on and now whenever someone does the same thing, you say to them "ahh, so you white-collared it huh!?".

Is there a term for to explain that?

Another example, I'm not sure if it's exactly the same, but say someone made a typo or similar for something, but it was humorous at the time, and now has caught on, so whenever said "thing" is mentioned, it is now referenced to in the manner they mistakenly typed it as.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The creation of a new word or phrase by someone is called coining a new word or phrase. The noun is coinage.

Lewis Carroll remains the past master of this in English (in my opinion). In all his major works, including: Alice's Adventures in Wonderland, Through the Looking Glass and The Hunting of the Snark.

Many have become firmly entrenched: chortle and galumph come to mind.

***The Jabberwocky*** abounds with them.

[Carroll's coinages](http://theweek.com/articles/468355/10-whimsical-words-coined-by-lewis-carroll)

[coinage](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coinage)

Comment: I believe that was the term I was looking for - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

### neologism

> A neologism is a newly coined word or term which has emerged into everyday usage.
>
> http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/neologism.htm

Examples (from the referenced link above):

- Sick
- D'oh
- Wicked
- To Google
- Metrosexual
- Noob
- Staycation
- Troll